# Animating a sequence of images in the background using Flex 3/Actionscript?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

I would like to animate a sequence of background images within a uicomponent but also dynamically add and remove components to this component.

My first question would be:
1.) What's the best way to animate a sequence of images using Flex 3?
2.) What's the best way to handle adding and removing components on top of the background dynamically?

Any help/information would greatly be appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mxml for your ui component declare an mx:Image  and give it an id.  Set up a timer loop that changes the "source" attribute (id.source = ) on your mx:Image  at an interval you like. To add and remove components dynamically just use addChild/removeChild or addElement/removeElement depending on the type of display object you're working with. The mx:Image  should always be behind the dynamically added components as it was created and added before them.

Comment: Thanks Greg for the help.  Your answer was perfect!